# After updating to macOS Big Sur I can't connect to my PostgreSQL database with MAMP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, mamp, macos-big-sur

#### Code

Here's the code that is throwing the error.

```
try {
  $myPDO = new PDO('pgsql:host=127.0.0.1:5432;dbname=test', 'test', '');
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
  echo var_dump($th);
}
```

#### Error

Here's the response I'm getting back from the try/catch.

```
object(PDOException)#2 (8) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "could not find driver"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(58) "/Users/test/index.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(8)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(58) "/Users/test/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(8)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__construct"
      ["class"]=>
      string(3) "PDO"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(46) "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1:5432;dbname=test"
        [1]=>
        string(13) "test"
        [2]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorInfo"]=>
  NULL
}
```

#### Versions

A list of the software versions I'm using.

**OS**: macOS Big Sur

**MAMP**: 6.2

**PHP**: 7.3.21

---

### Update - More Context

In the `php.ini` file the following lines are uncommented. This is the correct `php.ini` file according to PHP Info.

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/"
...
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Comment: Is it running? You'll need to check that the Postgres server process is alive, however MAMP does it.

Comment: Yep, Postgres is running. Postgres is running locally, separate from MAMP though.

Comment: It's possible you need to reinstall MAMP to make sure it links up with the right drivers.

Comment: Possibly, however I did update MAMP (from 5.x to 6.2) after I updated to Big Sur hoping that maybe that was my problem. I'll try this though.

Comment: The PHP version doesn't make a difference either, I've tried both PHP 7.3.21 and 7.4.9. I get the same error with both versions.

Comment: @tadman: I removed/uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled it but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue too. I'm using Symfony and start a local server using it's CLI. Hence, I don't think this is caused by the MAMP stack. Postgres itself is working fine. I can connect to the database using Postico without any problems.

Comment: Me too with Symfony server

Answer (score 2):

The default PHP installation on Big Sur doesn't include the required PostgreSQL driver. I installed PHP 7.4 via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) that does include this driver:

```
brew install php@7.4
```

Make sure to make this the default PHP version. I'm using [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh) so I need to run this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

You can find php.ini (in case you need to migrate configuration) here: */usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini*

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the tip! I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks that did for me. Just remember to `source ~/.zshrc` if you are going to immediately use the same shell