# Using Postgres with PHP 7.4 macOs Big Sur

Tags: php, postgresql, macos, apache, macos-big-sur

After update to macOs Big Sur and update PHP 7.3 -> 7.4.19 my postgres not working.

Extensions activated in php.ini

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

- PHP instaled using brew

Output command `php -m` not contains the module pdo_pgsql

Error output in command php artisan serve:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /opt/local/lib/php74/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_pgsql (dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php74/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_pgsql, 9): image not found), /opt/local/lib/php74/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php74/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @ChrisHaas this error is a generic for not connected database in Lumen Framework.  But the module is not showing up when I run the php -m command. I need to install the module separately but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422426/231316

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286153/8084062)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing PDO-drivers for PostgreSQL on Mac (using Zend for eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse)

Comment: @TharinduLakshan 
in Big Sur it was not as suggested but I had to do other similar procedures. As soon as I have time to fix the solution.